# Installing routing leaflet on an ionic2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I have installed a very basic ionic2 project that supports leaflet (https://github.com/SBejga/ionic2-map-leaflet). Then I executed

```
sudo npm install --save leaflet-routing-machine
```

in order to install leaflet routing machine. On map.ts I then had the following code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import "leaflet";
import "leaflet-routing-machine"

declare var L: any;

/*
  Generated class for the Map page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-map',
  templateUrl: 'map.html'
})
export class MapPage {
  map: L.Map;
  center: L.PointTuple;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MapPage');

    //set map center
    //this.center = [48.137154, 11.576124]; //Munich
    this.center = [48.775556, 9.182778]; //Stuttgart

    //setup leaflet map
    this.initMap();

    L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [
        L.latLng(48.776, 9.183),
        L.latLng(48.786, 9.193)
      ]
    }).addTo(this.map);

  }

  initMap() {
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: this.center,
      zoom: 13
    });

    //Add OSM Layer
    L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
      .addTo(this.map);
  }

}
```

The map seems to load properly but I don't get any routting. In console, I receive the message:

> router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/9.183,48.776;9.193,48.786?overview=false&alternatives=true&steps=true&hints=; Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503
>   (Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity) localhost/:1
>   Failed to load
>   https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/9.183,48.776;9.193,48.786?overview=false&alternatives=true&steps=true&hints=;:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
>   leaflet-routing-machine.js:10477 Routing error: Object

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Might be related, OSRM is unresponsive sometimes these days. You can see an error message as well (do not remember if it is similar) on [Leaflet Routing Machine demo page](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/) when it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

For running on chrome, install the chrome plugin [Allow Control allow origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm) and enable it.